# No Saml2 Response found in the http request

Tags: .net, saml-2.0, sustainsys-saml2

Can someone explain why 1 scenario is working as expected but another one is not?

I am getting an error when redirecting from IDP after authentication.

```
Exception: No Saml2 Response found in the http request.
Controller: Saml2
Action: Acs

   at Sustainsys.Saml2.WebSso.AcsCommand.Run(HttpRequestData request, IOptions options)
   at Sustainsys.Saml2.Mvc.Saml2Controller.Acs()
```

But I do see a SAML token in the redirect url on http-post.

```
2019-03-12 20:27:34 xxx.xxx.xxx.130 POST /sampleapp/Saml2/Acs - 9090 - xxx.xxx.xxx.139 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/72.0.3626.121+Safari/537.36 https://xxx.idp.com:8443/nidp/saml2/sso?
```

> SAMLRequest=lZGxTsMwEIb3Sn0Hy3vjxGmb5tRGiuhSqQjUlg5sjmMRi8QOPqfw%2BFgBBGVAYv3P33f%2BdWsUXct7KAffmIN6GRR68ta1BuFjsqGDM2AFagQjOoXgJRzL2z3wKIbeWW%2BlbelP5m9EICrntTWU7LYbquuqTvN0sVokPEvnchlXyyrh9bIWcpFVmcgpOSuHAdjQwAcKcVA7g14YH6I4yWdxOkv4icfAM0j5IyXbUEMb4Ueq8b5HYKy1T9pECtHOBuEj2QjnlYuk7WA1n6fM6LpnYwMW3lBSfv30xhocOuWOyl20VA%2BH%2Fbe0V%2BL5otXrbyW7P92dQ86Oo7CUSIvphJD1uADGEq74n2XNruDp5DO4Pl%2FxDg%3D%3D&RelayState=v2xJuO8SAvQlp-hmfNC5-YUA

500 0 0 359

I have a similar redirect to port 443 and that works fine but a redirect to 9090 from a load balancer fails with the above error.
The application is behind a load balancer and I am using publicOrigin configuration to have the public url of the root.

2019-03-12 20:31:11 xxx.xxx.xxx.130 POST /sampleapp/Saml2/Acs - 443 - 192.168.127.139 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/72.0.3626.121+Safari/537.36 https://xxx.idp.com:8443/nidp/saml2/sso?SAMLRequest=nZHBTsMwDIbvk%2FYOUe5r0q5jXbRVqthl0hBoGztwS1NDI9qkxOng8QkdE%2BzCgavt77N%2FeYmybZJOFL2vzQ7eekBPPtrGoDh3VrR3RliJGoWRLaDwSuyLu61IIi46Z71VtqG%2Fmb8RiQjOa2so2axXVFdlxUGWs4SnGU9BQlYmcl5l2c08nS2eU0XJERwGYEUDHyjEHjYGvTQ%2BlHi8mPDpJE4OCRfTWMT8iZJ1iKGN9ANVe9%2BhYKyxL9pEgGgnvfSRqqXz4CJlW5Gl6ZQZXXVsSMDCDCXF5dJba7Bvwe3BnbSCx932R9qBfD1peD8rresu3qD9UrOHw%2F0x9Nl%2BEBcKaT4eEbIcFokhjMv%2FZ1uyK8l49F24fmf%2BCQ%3D%3D&RelayState=zcs5p1LobhrHqJdC57eJHbUR 302 0 0 609

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please include more information of the request to Saml2/Acs in the case where it doesn't work. Is it a POST or a GET? Query string contents? Request body contents?

Comment: @AndersAbel - I did include those information. It's a POST on 9090 port with SAMLRequest query string and error 500. What more information will be helpful?

Comment: No. The SamlRequest is in the referral. I asked for the body contents of the post.